# How to insert a list into another list without concatenating them

Tags: sml

For example say I have a list `[1,5,10]`, how would I put it into an empty list making it `[[1,5,10]`?

Comment: Since the answer is trivial – you write `[[1,5,10]]`– I suspect that there's a specific piece of code that you're having problems with, and you'll have a better chance of a useful answer if you add that context.

Answer (score 0):

Since `[[1,5,10]` is not a valid list, I assume you mean `[[1,5,10]]`, that is, an *int list list*. You can create such a list simply as you just did: `[[1,5,10]]`. Doing this for an arbitrary *int list* could be accomplished like:

```
fun singleton (xs : int list) = [xs]

val test_1 = singleton [1,5,10]  (* = [[1,5,10]] *)
```

No concatenation occurred, since this is synonymous to:

```
- [1,5,10] :: [];
> val it = [[1, 5, 10]] : int list list
```

That is, putting the list `[1,5,10]` in front of the empty list.

This demonstrates the `::` (cons) operator. If you ever want to put multiple elements (e.g. multiple *int list*s) in front of each other, this is what you call concatenation, and you use the `@` (append) operator, e.g. like:

```
- [1,5,10] @ [11,15,20]
> val it = [1, 5, 10, 11, 15, 20] : int list
```

Lastly, there is the `List.concat` operator that takes a list of lists and appends them all:

```
- List.concat [ [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9] ];
> val it = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] : int list
```

---

A good exercise at this point is to define this recursive function:

```
fun my_concat [] = ...
  | my_concat (xs :: xss) = ...
```

where `xs` is the first list in the list of lists, and `xss` is the remaining list of lists.

(I've tried to highlight that by giving `xs` a plural name, and `xss` a double-plural name.)